# Why is my application breaking when I try to access a http.get response?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to access a remote url and just output it, this works:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    http.get({
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 80,
        path: '/',
        agent: false  // create a new agent just for this one request
    }, (response) => {
        console.log('foo');
    });
});
```

but when I do:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    http.get({
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 80,
        path: '/',
        agent: false  // create a new agent just for this one request
    }, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

I get a `Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.` I also tried `res.send(response)`

I'm not sure about my settings, but if I write localhost:80, I get the page I'm trying to log

Comment: Check the request in your browser’s dev tools – what does the server response look like?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the server is breaking because I didn't output any data. I needed to something like

```
res.render();
```